# Doxygen confused between documentation of function and inner class

Tags: c++, function, doxygen, inner-classes

Doxygen 1.8.10

In a class, I have a function within which an inner class is declared.

```
/*! This is a test class 
*/ 
class TestClass { 

/*! \brief A function which does something 
 *  \param param_A this is the first parameter of doSomething function 
 *  \param param_B this is the second parameter of doSomething function 
 */ 
void doSomething(int param_A, int param_B) { 

/*! This is an inner Test Class 
*/ 
class InnerTestClass { 

/*! \brief A constructor for InnerTestClass 
 *  \param param_C this is the parameter for the InnerTestClass inner class constructor 
 */ 
InnerTestClass (int param_C) { 

} 

}
```

When I generate the doxygen documentation for the above class, a confusion occurs between the documentation for the function doSomething and the inner class InnerTestClass.

1. No inner class documentation file called classInnerTestClass.html is created.
2. In the documentation for classTestClass.html, the documentation for the InnerTestClass is included with the documentation for the function, as follows:

   doSomething(int param_A 
               int param_B 
               )

A function which does something

Parameters 
        param_A this is the first parameter of doSomething function 
        param_B this is the second parameter of doSomething function

This is an inner Test Class

Parameters 
        param_C this is the parameter for the InnerTestClass inner class constructor

3. Warning messages are shown indicating that param_A and param_B are not documented and that param_C is not found in the argument list of doSomething.

Comment: There is missing closing bracket in your code,you should correct it first.

Comment: See also Bug 754818 - Doxygen confused between documentation of function and inner class (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754818)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs/Classes defined inside functions/methods are considered implementation details and cannot be documented (just like you cannot document an individual for loop or if statement).

Think about doxygen as a tool to document the *public* API. If you still want to show the implementation as well, document it with normal comments and set `INLINE_SOURCES` to `YES` in the config file.